# How to perform a two Part XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

How would I change this

```
<CHAPT>
  <CHAPTNO>1.1</CHAPTNO>
  <SUBJ>Introduction</SUBJ>
  <P>foo text</P>
  <P>foo text</P>  .. and so on
</CHAPT>
```

To this:

```
<p class="chapheader"><span class="chapnumbers">1.1 </span>Introduction</p>
<P>foo text</P>
<P>foo text</P>
```

***But***, only where `<CHAPTNO>` directly precedes `<SUBJ>`  ..because there are other `<SUBJ>` in the XML that do not follow a `<CHAPTNO>` and I do not want those stand alone Subject Lines formatted as a Chapter header.

I'm new to XSLT and got stuck on my second template.

Comment: Can you please provide a more complete XML snippet?  Is each elements pair encased in some other element?

Comment: I posted some edits. I hope that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Here is my example XML ( I added a root element just for the test):

```
<root>
<CHAPT>
  <CHAPTNO>1.1</CHAPTNO>
  <SUBJ>Introduction1111</SUBJ>
  <P>foo text</P>
  <P>foo text</P>  
</CHAPT>
<CHAPT>
  <SUBJ>Introduction2222</SUBJ>
  <P>foo text</P>
  <P>foo text</P>  
</CHAPT>
<CHAPT>
  <CHAPTNO>3333</CHAPTNO>
  <SUBJ>Introduction3333</SUBJ>
  <P>foo text</P>
  <P>foo text</P>  
</CHAPT>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="root/CHAPT">
        <xsl:if test="SUBJ[count(../CHAPTNO)=1]">
           <p class="chapheader"> 
           <span class="chapnumbers"><xsl:value-of select="CHAPTNO"/></span>
                     <xsl:value-of select="SUBJ"/>
             </p>
        </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Resulting Output:

```
<p class="chapheader"><span class="chapnumbers">1.1</span>Introduction1111</p>
<p class="chapheader"><span class="chapnumbers">3333</span>Introduction3333</p>
```

Comment: The <if> test is reads as: locate the SUBJ element where a prececing CHAPTNO element exists.

Comment: That worked great thanks. Pretty interesting code.. I wouldn't have thought of at my current skill level.